# Dummy Output - Pop OS, HP Omen 15 with Bang And Olufsen speakers

Tags: audio

```
niranjan@pop-os:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                  HDA NVidia at 0xb4000000 irq 17

niranjan@pop-os:~$ lspci -vvv | grep -A8 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10) (prog-if 80)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 32, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
Region 0: Memory at b441c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Region 4: Memory at b4100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio         Controller (rev a1)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
Region 0: Memory at b4000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

[image: alsamixer only displays this card.]

[image]

I can't get any audio to work, I have B&O speakers, been stuck with dummy output as an output device from install of pop OS. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem, after a months of digging this thing i found solution.

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

This is not problem with your sound drivers, it looks like kernel from 5.0 has this issue. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and everything worked, so it led me to conclusion that this is kernel(alsa driver) problem not the ubuntu problem.
After months of digging i found those commands on this website https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html with great explanation.
Commands i posted worked on ubuntu 20.04 and Fedora 32 (this is what i've tested)
Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

i just installed popos on my omen 17 with a similar set of commands:

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf  
echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

thought i'd post this in case anyone else is looking around.  aside from the dummy sound the installation went flawlessly.